# How to destroy child object of other player in UNET?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, unity-networking

Right now, I have a multiplayer game where the player fires projectiles at other players that have a certain amount of bubbles. Once a player has lost all of their bubbles, they lose.

The issue I had previously was that on one screen, a first player could shoot out a second player's bubbles, but not all of the bubbles on the second player's screen would be popped, so I am trying to sync it over the network somehow.

The issue I'm seeing is that NetworkServer.Destroy requires finding the GameObject you intend to destroy by its NetworkIdentity, but only the root Player GameObject is allowed to have the NetworkIdentity component on it. What's the best way I can sync the destruction of a child object of a player?

Comment: I am not well acquainted with networking, but here is a suggestion for a possible solution.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html

You could give each child object a unique non-network ID and make a remote action call (see the link), which would then tell each client/server to Destroy the object, sort of making your own NetworkServer.Destroy call in a way.

Answer (score 0):

The https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/ course is very similar to the game you describe. It has a Bullet script attached to the fired bullets. If the bullets touched something, it check if it's a player, and apply damage to it (the player prefab has a `Health` script attached to it).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        var hit = collision.gameObject;

        /* Code below is from the original example
        var health = hit.GetComponent<Health>();
        if (health  != null)
        {
            health.TakeDamage(10);
        }*/

        var bubble = hit.GetComponent<BubbleBehavior>();
        if (bubble != null)
        {
            bubble.Popped(); // Implement a Popped function doing the magic
        }

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

In your case you can do the same, but instead of checking if the touched object is a player, simply check if it is a bubble, and do whatever you want from the touched bubble.

In the original example, they sync the health (it is a "SyncVar"), in your case you can sync the number of bubbles remaining.

Comment: So in this one, you'd be adding a networkbehavior to the bubbles? Don't all network behaviors need to be spawned individually?

Comment: The bubbles are child of a player GameObject which already has a network behavior so I would say that a "simple" MonoBehavior should be okay, then because Bubble popping need to be sync, the touched bubble can call a command of its parent network behavior. I think this would work. If you haven't already read it, I really advise you to look at the tuto I linked, specially parts 10, 11, 12 and 13.